# unable to populate objects with XML file in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse a simple XML file in a Xamarin (Visual Studio) Forms app. I am using the example [provided here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WorkingWithFiles/)

It does not work. The serializer returns a list of Node objects, but they are empty. I am including my code below, but it should be identical to the example with some name changes. My XML file is in the Solution root and its Build Action is configured as an Embedded Resource.

```
namespace EZCal
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        // description of a menu tree node
        public class Node
        {
            // TODO: move strings to external file so they can be Localized
            public int id { get; set; }             // the ID of this node. Never null
            public int idParent { get; set; }       // NULL for top-level nodes
            public String desc1 { get; set; }       // text to be displayed - line 1
            public String desc2 { get; set; }       // text to be displayed - line 1
            public String command { get; set; }     // command string to be sent to device
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.parseXML();
        }

        void parseXML() {

            var assembly = System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(MainPage)).Assembly;
            System.IO.Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("EZCal.MenuDefinitions.xml");
            List<Node> menuNodes;

            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Node>));
                menuNodes = (List<Node>) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
            var listView = new ListView();
            listView.ItemsSource = menuNodes;
        }
   }
}
```

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ArrayOfNode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Node>
        <NodeId>1</NodeId>
        <ParentId>0</ParentId>
        <Display1>Home line 1</Display1>
        <Display2>Home line 2</Display2>
        <Command>Home Command</Command>
    </Node>
    <Node>
        <NodeId>2</NodeId>
        <ParentId>1</ParentId>
        <Display1>Help line 1</Display1>
        <Display2>Help line 2</Display2>
        <Command>Help Command</Command>
    </Node>
    <Node>
        <NodeId>3</NodeId>
        <ParentId>1</ParentId>
        <Display1>Diags line 1</Display1>
        <Display2>Diags line 2</Display2>
        <Command>Diags Command</Command>
    </Node>
    <Node>
        <NodeId>4</NodeId>
        <ParentId>1</ParentId>
        <Display1>Access line 1</Display1>
        <Display2>Access line 2</Display2>
        <Command>Access Command</Command>
    </Node>
    </Node>
</ArrayOfNode>
```

Comment: the names of the properties in your Node class do not have any relation to the names of the properties in the XML file.  They either need to match, or you need to provide a mapping

Comment: @Jason that worked. thank you. I you want to post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names of the properties in your model need to match the names of the nodes in your XML in order for the deserialization to work automatically.

Alternatively, you can apply a mapping attribute

```
[XmlElement("NodeId")]
public int id { get; set; }
```

Comment: I originally renamed the properties in my Model to match the XML. That worked. But I prefer this method - it makes clear the linkage to the XML tags. Thank you.